# How can I show automatically registered users geolocation in a global map with google maps api as they register?

Tags: api, google-maps, geolocation, registration

I'm trying to show all users geolocation from a web site in a map. Through google maps API documentation I've got a way to show my location as user. But, how I make it for show all geolocation from the registered people on the website?

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step please apply proper formatting and identation to your code, its a mess to read right now.

Comment: Sorry. Hope now it's better.

Comment: So if im understanding correct your want to add markers at the coordinates of registered users on the map? If yes: The same way youre showing your own geolocation, just add markers with the lat/lng coordinates of your registered users.

Comment: See my answer below on how to set additional markers

Comment: You need to send the result of the geolocation back to your server and store it for display.  Note that some users my have privacy concerns with your doing that.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the support. I've been searching and have found many information. But still in all options I've to enter the lat and lang from the users like you say Fabian. But that it's not what I'm looking for. Is there a way to get automatically, without asking or written manually, the geolocation  and show it in a global map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create objects of the `google.maps.Marker()` type, set a position using the `setPosition` function of it and add it to your map using the `setMap` function.

Example (Lat/Lng is the center of Germany - insert your users coordinates there):

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker();  
// use your registered user coordinates here
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(48.14544, 8.19208)); 
marker.setMap(map);
```

Additionally you can use boundaries to make your map autozoom to get every marker visible:

```
var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
...
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
...
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```